# checkboxes & radiobuttons images

Tags: jquery, html

is there a way to replace the images that represent checkboxes & radiobuttons for specific ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [**ezMark: Stylize Checkbox & Radiobutton**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ezmark)

Comment: thanks. that did the trick. btw, do you know of a way of doing the same thing but with the arrow in a dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

think so, jQuery UI or http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=180789